# Appium cannot find ADB path even though appium-doctor passes

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

Appium Doctor passes
[image: Appium doctor passes]

This is in my bash_profile
[image: This is in my bash_profile]

I am still seeing this issue

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Could not find adb Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Comment: Have you tried "source ~/.bash_profile" after updating the bash profile?

Comment: Yes I have tried that.

Comment: I have added `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` to my `PATH`, perhaps that'll work for you.

Comment: If you view the screenshot you will see I already had those in my path.

Comment: Is this fixed ?